# What HTTP response headers are required

Tags: http, http-headers, httpresponse

What HTTP response headers are required to be sent from server to the client?

I working to optimize the HTTP response headers to minimize the HTTP response overhead. I know "overhead" is somewhat exaggerated, but I like a clean output.

I see a lot of websites sending redundant cache headers, etc..

e.g.

It is redundant to specify both `Expires` and `Cache-Control: max-age`, or to specify both `Last-Modified` and `ETag`.

- [Source](http://code.google.com/intl/en/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html#LeverageBrowserCaching)
- HTTP/1.1: Header Field Definitions

Answer (score 78):

It depends on what you define as being required: there are no header fields that must be sent with every response no matter what the circumstances are, but there are header fields that you really *should* send. The only header field that comes close is `Date`, but even it has circumstances under which it is not required.

In the parlance of [RFC 2119](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119), the term **MUST** means that something is a requirement of the specification and not meeting the requirement would be invalid. There are no header fields defined by RFCs [7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230), [7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), [7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232), [7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233), [7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234), or [7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235) that **MUST** be sent by an origin server *in all cases*.

---

The following headers, for example, can be omitted (though you probably should send them):

#### [7.1.1.2. Date](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.1.2)

> An origin server MUST NOT send a `Date` header field if it does not
> have a clock capable of providing a reasonable approximation of the
> current instance in Coordinated Universal Time. An origin server MAY
> send a `Date` header field if the response is in the 1xx
> (Informational) or 5xx (Server Error) class of status codes. An
> origin server MUST send a `Date` header field in all other cases.

Note the last sentence of the quote. The `Date` header field **MUST** be sent if the origin server is capable of providing a "reasonable approximation" of the date in UTC, but there is nothing stopping a server from misrepresenting itself.

#### [7.4.2. Server](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.4.2)

> An origin server MAY generate a `Server` field in its responses.

#### [3.3.2. Content-Length](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.2)

> Aside from [a finite number of predefined cases], in the absence of
> `Transfer-Encoding`, an origin server SHOULD send a `Content-Length`
> header field when the payload body size is known prior to sending the
> complete header section.

On the subject of `Content-Length` and `Transfer-Encoding`, note that neither can be sent, in which case the length of the response is "determined by the number of octets received prior to the server closing the connection."

#### [3.1.1.5. Content-Type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5)

> If a `Content-Type` header field is not present, the recipient
> MAY either assume a media type of `application/octet-stream`
> (RFC2046, Section 4.5.1) or examine the data to determine its type.

---

There are circumstances under which particular headers can be required, for example:

- [An origin server that does not support persistent connections **MUST** send the `Connection: close` in every response that does not have a 1xx status code.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-6.1)
- [An origin server **MUST** generate an `Allow` header in a 405 (Method Not Allowed) response.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.4.1)
- [An origin server generating a 401 (Unauthorized) response **MUST** send a `WWW-Authenticate` header field containing at least one challenge.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.1)

Answer (score 27):

It depends on the specifics of the response, but generally, a response from an origin server should have:

- Date
- Content-Type
- Server

and either Content-Length, Transfer-Encoding or Connection: close.

If you want to do caching, add Cache-Control (e.g., with max-age); Expires isn't generally necessary any more. If you want clients to be able to validate, add Last-Modified or ETag.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I don't think the "Server"-header is important. It's also a little security protection to avoid this header-entry. Attackers haven't "any" informations like "OS/Webserver/-version".

Comment: BTW: the default value of the "Connection"-response entry is the value from the requested header-entry "Connection: close/keep-alive"?

Comment: Server isn't strictly required, but some clients seem to want it, IIRC. Definitely do cut it down to the bare minimum. WRT Connection: no, it's what the server intends to do with the connection; it chooses which to send.

Comment: would love a reference to a specification so this wasn't just a says-so answer.

Comment: Strictly speaking, none of them is required; if you look through RFC2616 (and httpbis docs) you'll see that Date can be omitted if the origin server doesn't have a clock; content-type can be omitted (defaults to application/octet-stream) and server is encouraged but not required with a MUST. This is at least partially because we need to be somewhat backwards-compatible with HTTP/0.9, which didn't have headers at all. however, for a response to be useful, it does need some.

Comment: @algal When it comes from one of the spec writers I think it's okay.

Comment: I'd be very surprised to see a `Content-Type` header on a `201 No Content`  response.

Comment: Date is needed only for Cache-Control. I tested Chrome and Firefox and caching perfectly works without Date header so it can be safely omitted. It's just insane that in spec the header is mandatory.

Comment: I sent an email to WG were asked to change MUST to MAY for the Date  https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2020JulSep/0142.html