# What are the required HTTP headers fields

Tags: http, header

I know that any HTTP request will require the following headers fields .

- HOST

I found this document that describes some of the [HTTP Header fields](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) but does not have a list of the required ones.

My questions are;

- What other headers fields are required?
- What are the suggested header fields?

Comment: It looks like HOST is the only required header field

Comment: possible duplicate of [What HTTP response headers are required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726515/what-http-response-headers-are-required)

Comment: Ignore the above comment, I've incorrectly flagged the question as a duplicate.

Comment: To answer this question we need to know the request type, http version, role of the application, capabilities of the application etc. For example if the client does not support persistent connections and the http version is 1.1 the Connection header is required. If the application is a proxy and is forwarding a request the Via header is required.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What, at the bare minimum, is required for an HTTP request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686261/what-at-the-bare-minimum-is-required-for-an-http-request) for request, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726515/what-http-response-headers-are-required for response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like HOST is the only required header field

Comment: It is only required in version 1.1. 1.0 does not require this.