# Http response with no http header

Tags: http, http-headers

I have written a mini-minimalist http server prototype ( heavily inspired by boost asio examples ), and for the moment I haven't put any http header in the server response, only the html string content. Surprisingly it works just fine.

[In that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726515/clean-http-response-header) the OP wonders about necessary fields in the http response, and one of the comments states that they may not be really important from the server side.

I have not tried yet to respond binary image files, or gzip compressed file for the moment, in which cases I suppose it is mandatory to have a http header.

But for text only responses (html, css, and xml outputs), would it be ok **never** to include the http header in my server responses ? What are the risks / errors possible ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At a minimum, you **must** provide a header with a status line and a date.

As someone who has written many protocol parsers, **I am begging you**, on my digital metaphoric knees, please oh please oh please don't just totally ignore the specification just because your favorite browser lets you get away with it.

It is perfectly fine to create a program that is minimally functional, as long as the data it produces is correct.  This should not be a major burden, since all you have to do is add three lines to the start of your response.  And one of those lines is *blank*!  Please take a few minutes to write the **two glorious line of code** that will bring your response data into line with the spec.

The headers you really should supply are:

- the status line (required)
- a date header (required)
- content-type (highly recommended)
- content-length (highly recommended), unless you're using chunked encoding
- if you're returning HTTP/1.1 status lines, and you're not providing a valid content-length or using chunked encoding, then add `Connection: close` to your headers
- the blank line to separate header from body (required)

You can choose not to send a content-type with the response, but you have to understand that the client might not know what to do with the data.  The client has to guess what kind of data it is.  A browser might decide to treat it as a downloaded file instead of displaying it.  An automated process (someone's bash/curl script) might reasonably decide that the data isn't of the expected type so it should be thrown away.

From the [HTTP/1.1 Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) section 3.1.1.5.  Content-Type:

> A sender that generates a message containing a payload body SHOULD
> generate a Content-Type header field in that message unless the
> intended media type of the enclosed representation is unknown to the
> sender.  If a Content-Type header field is not present, the recipient
> MAY either assume a media type of "application/octet-stream"
> ([RFC2046], Section 4.5.1) or examine the data to determine its type.

Comment: you won, I'm currently writting the small method to had the header to my outputs.

Comment: Would meta tags specifying the headers work as well? I mean do clients automatically understand that? Or will I have to manually check if headers exist via meta tags?

Comment: Any standard desktop/mobile client should understand meta tags in HTML.  But if your data will be consumed by some other kind of software, you can't depend on a full-featured HTML implementation.

Comment: From what I understand of the RFC 2616 spec, date is not strictly required, if you look at section 14.18 (Date header) https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.18 it says: "If the server does not have a clock that can provide a reasonable approximation of the current time, its responses MUST NOT include a Date header field. In this case, the rules in section 14.18.1 MUST be followed." This applies in my case with IoT device without RTC (it would be complex to query date from external server)