# Error in http.get in node (PARSE ERROR)

Tags: node.js, parse-error

```
http.get({host:'192.168.2.104'},function(res){
console.log("test");
.
.
```

Creates following error:

```
Error: Parse Error
at Error (native)
at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:362:20)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:547:20)
```

curl response from server:

```
root@kali:~# curl http://192.168.2.104 -v
* Rebuilt URL to: http://192.168.2.104/
*   Trying 192.168.2.104...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.2.104 (192.168.2.104) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.2.104
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.2.104 left intact
{"uptime":4561488,"error":0,"temp":34.30,"humidity":28.60}
```

Server is very simple and adds NO HEADERS to HTTP Response
Can't find a solution

Comment: It would be better to show the verbose output from cURL so we might see what part of the server response is invalid.

Comment: An HTTP response with no headers is not a valid HTTP response so cannot be parsed as an HTTP response.  A status header is the minimum required.

Comment: status header is in but nothing else, updated curl out

Comment: `date:` seems to be required also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483781/http-response-with-no-http-header

Comment: The [Node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) say the following: "`hostname` `<string>` Alias for host. To support url.parse(), hostname is preferred over host."  Maybe give `hostname` a shot?