# How should a HTTP client handle a response without headers?

Tags: http

I'm writing a HTTP client, and wondering if HTTP responses are required to have any headers?

So is the following a valid HTTP response? (where `\r\n` == CRLF). How should a client handle it?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
\r\n
```

---

The related questions [Http response with no http header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483781/http-response-with-no-http-header) and  [What HTTP response headers are required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726515/what-http-response-headers-are-required) are similar, but I think they are subtly-but-crucially different. They are both from the point of view of a server generating headers, rather than a parser parsing a response.

For example, a detailed answer to the current question could include how the client should interpret the above minimal response: whether it should accept the 200 response or abort, and what it should do with the underlying connection in terms of keeping it open or closing it.

Comment: check RFC2616 for further informations on this: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Http response with no http header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483781/http-response-with-no-http-header)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What HTTP response headers are required](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4726515/11683)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What HTTP response headers are required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726515/what-http-response-headers-are-required)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the message is defined in RFC 7231 (see https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#http.message), and that says that header fields are syntactically optional. So a message *parser* should accept that.