# Converting matplotlib png to base64 for viewing in html template

Tags: python, html, matplotlib, flask, base64

#### Background

Hello, I am trying to make a simple web app, following a tutorial, that calculates a dampened vibration equation and returns a png of the result to the html page after it has been converted to a Base64 string.

#### Problem

The app functions normally except that when the result is calculated, a broken image icon is returned, likely because the Base64 string is not valid.

#### Troubleshooting

I have converted another png image to a Base64 string using an online converter and used `<img src="data:image/png;base64, BASE64_STRING"/>` to display the image successfully. I believe the template is appropriately formatted. I have also read other SO answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107414/passing-a-matplotlib-figure-to-html-flask) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091129/what-is-the-difference-among-idioms-for-serving-a-matplotlib-image-with-flask) and tried implementing those without success.

#### Relevant code

**Here is where the image string is returned**

```
from numpy import exp, cos, linspace
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def damped_vibrations(t, A, b, w):
    return A*exp(-b*t)*cos(w*t)


def compute(A, b, w, T, resolution=500):
    """Return filename of plot of the damped_vibration function."""
    t = linspace(0, T, resolution+1)
    u = damped_vibrations(t, A, b, w)
    plt.figure()  # needed to avoid adding curves in plot
    plt.plot(t, u)
    plt.title('A=%g, b=%g, w=%g' % (A, b, w))

    from io import BytesIO
    figfile = BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(figfile, format='png')
    figfile.seek(0)  # rewind to beginning of file
    import base64
    #figdata_png = base64.b64encode(figfile.read())
    figdata_png = base64.b64encode(figfile.getvalue())
    return figdata_png
```

**Here is where the image is displayed**

```
{% if result != None %}
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ result }}"\>
{% endif %}
```

If needed, I can provide the controller file as well. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The beginning of the data in the template gives a clue to what's happening.  `&#39;` is the HTML entity for a single quote `'`.  Combined with the preceding b, `b'`, it looks like the representation of a byte string, rather than the contents of the string.

Decode the byte string to a string before trying to render them with Jinja.

```
render_template('result.html', result=figdata_png.decode('utf8'))
```

Jinja renders the *string representation* of objects in `{{ }}`.  The string representation of a byte string includes the `b''` to distinguish it from a Unicode string.  So you have to decode in order to display their value directly.

Answer (score -3):

Try adding the section **meta charset="utf-8"** into the HEAD section of your template. That worked for me :-)

Comment: For those wondering why this answer is downvoted, see the answer by @Martijn Pieters [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28657010/dangers-of-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8/29832646#29832646)