# How to create an BytesIO img and pass to template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, bytesio

### AIM

I am attempting to:

1. Create a histogram,
2. Store it temporary memory,
3. Pass the image to the template.

I am having trouble with Step 3 above. I suspect that I am making a simple and fundamental error in relation to passing the `context` data to the template.

### ERROR

HTML is rendering with a broken image tag.

### CODE

**Views.py**

```
class SearchResultsView(DetailView):

   ...

   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.get_histogram(request)
        return super(SearchResultsView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchResultsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context


    def get_histogram(self, request):
        """ Function to create and save histogram of Hashtag.locations """
        # create the histogram
        plt.show()
        img_in_memory = BytesIO()
        plt.savefig(img_in_memory, format="png")
        image = base64.b64encode(img_in_memory.getvalue())
        context = {'image':image}
        return context
```

**Results.html**

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{image}}" alt="Location Histogram" />
```

## SOLUTION

In addition to issues with `get` and `get_context_data` as outlined by @ruddra below, another issue was that I had to decode the base64 string as a Unicode string. For more information, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31492525/converting-matplotlib-png-to-base64-for-viewing-in-html-template).

To do so, I included: `image = image.decode('utf8')`

So that, **views.py** looks like this:

```
def get_histogram(self, request):
    # draw histogram
    plt.show()
    img_in_memory = BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(img_in_memory, format="png") # save the image in memory using BytesIO
    img_in_memory.seek(0) # rewind to beginning of file
    image = base64.b64encode(img_in_memory.getvalue()) # load the bytes in the context as base64
    image = image.decode('utf8')
    return {'image':image}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the `get_histogram` in wrong way. You can do it like this:

```
class SearchResultsView(DetailsView):
    ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         context = super(SearchResultsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         context.update(self.get_histogram(self.request))
         return context
```

You don't need to call the `get_histogram` method in `get`, or override the `get` method.

#### Update

I have tried like this:

```
 class SearchResultsView(DetailsView):
     ...

     def get_histogram(self):
         x = 2
         y = 3
         z = 2
         t= 3    
         plt.plot(x, y)
         plt.plot(z, t)
         plt.show()
         img_in_memory = io.BytesIO()  # for Python 3
         plt.savefig(img_in_memory, format="png")
         image = base64.b64encode(img_in_memory.getvalue())
         return {'image':image}

     def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
         context = super(SearchResultsView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
         context.update(self.get_histogram())
         return context
```

Output looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @ruddra, I've amended `get` as advised. However, `results.html` is still rendering with a broken image tag where I expect the histogram to be!

Comment: @ycrad I have added how I have written the code. Please have a look.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not working; a broken HTML image is still loading. As it works for the example you posted, I now know that my mistake must be somewhere else in the code. If it's of any assistance, I included a link to the repo in the query above.

Comment: Sorry, I might not be able to help you with your repo, but I might help you to debug the issue. In the templates, just put `{{image}}` in somewhere, without the tags and check if there is anything coming through context. If you get nothing, in that case, there could be issue with image generation.

Comment: If I do as you suggest, an encoded base64 string is returned.

Comment: That means, you are being able send data from view to template, but the problem resides elsewhere, maybe in plotting.

Comment: Thanks @ruddra, I don't believe that it is in the plotting, as I've used your plotting example, and it still doesn't work. Instead, I now suspect that the issue may be caused by the fact that 'styles.css' isn't loading properly. Anyway, I'm sure it's outside the ambit of the original query, so have marked your answer as accepted.

Comment: Just to let you know, I included the solution in the query @ruddra, thanks again :)