# How to base64 encode a html_string

Tags: python, django, base64, stringio

### AIM

I am attempting to encode a `folium` choropleth as `StringIO`. I am basing my answer of a [related query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53127869/how-to-create-an-bytesio-img-and-pass-to-template/53133673?noredirect=1#comment93294028_53133673). I have checked the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689365/python-3-typeerror-must-be-str-not-bytes-with-sys-stdout-write) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45482272/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-python-2-to-3).

### ERROR

```
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

### CODE

**views.py**

```
def get_choropleth(self, request):
    # make choropleth ('m')
    html_string = m.get_root().render()
    f = StringIO(html_string)
    choropleth = base64.b64decode(f.read())
    choropleth = choropleth.encode('utf8') # causing error
    return {'choropleth':choropleth}
```

Comment: simply try to replace `choropleth.encode('utf8')` by `choropleth.decode('utf8')` and please refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode)

Comment: well `b'\xe0'.decode('latin')` will output `'à'`. So, maybe your string isn't really `utf8` compliant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial-and-error, the following worked for me:

### SOLUTION

```
def get_choropleth(self, request):
        # make choropleth ('m')
        html_string = m.get_root().render()
        encoded_bytes = html_string.encode('utf-8')
        encoded_bytes = base64.b64encode(encoded_bytes)
        encoded_bytes = encoded_bytes.decode('utf8') # decode the b64 bytes for Unicode
        choropleth = encoded_bytes
        return {'choropleth':choropleth}
```