# Send requests from Chrome extension that have 'Date' header

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

According to [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader%28%29-method), all sent XHRs with 'Date' header are terminated.

I am working on an extension that interacts with web server api that requires the 'Date' headers to be sent as part of the request.

Is there a different way to send the date header from chrome extension?

Comment: Do you have any control over the API? Can you maybe use a custom `X-Data` header?

Comment: re: `all sent XHRs with 'Date' header are terminated.`   Not according to my reading of the [specification](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-setrequestheader%28%29-method) . It says "the remaining STEPS are teminated." And the steps refer to how a header is set into the request.  The request itself still gets sent, but without the forbidden header.

Answer (score 0):

There's no special mechanism to do XHR from Chrome extensions. The same behavior should apply, and you should be able to set headers as in a regular web context.

Seems like a broken API though. This might help: [What's the rationale behind the HTTP Date header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610254/whats-the-rationale-behind-the-http-date-header)