# Unity, NTP time, gets blocked

Tags: time, unity-game-engine, ntp

I am using Unity3D to create a game.

i need to get NTP time in order players not to cheat by setting their computer time to the future in order to get bonuses.

I can get the time for desktop application but when i switch to Web Player it gets blocked.

Any suggestions?

My code is this :

```
static string[] servers = new string[] {
"time.nist.gov",
"time-b.nist.gov",
"time-a.nist.gov",
"nist1-ny.ustiming.org",
"nist1-chi.ustiming.org",
"ntp-nist.ldsbc.edu",
"nist1-la.ustiming.org" 
};

public static DateTime GetNISTDate(){
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
try
{
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient(servers[i], 13).GetStream());
serverResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
Debug.Log(serverResponse);
reader.Close();
// Check to see that the signature is there
if (serverResponse.Length > 47 && serverResponse.Substring(38, 9).Equals("UTC(NIST)")) {
// Parse the date
int jd = int.Parse(serverResponse.Substring(1, 5));
int yr = int.Parse(serverResponse.Substring(7, 2));
int mo = int.Parse(serverResponse.Substring(10, 2));
int dy = int.Parse(serverResponse.Substring(13, 2));
int hr = int.Parse(serverResponse.Substring(16, 2));
int mm = int.Parse(serverResponse.Substring(19, 2));
int sc = int.Parse(serverResponse.Substring(22, 2));
if (jd > 51544)
yr += 2000;
else
yr += 1999;
date = new DateTime(yr, mo, dy, hr, mm, sc);
Debug.Log(date);
break;
}
}
catch{
}
}
return date;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Unity Web Player, but that sure sounds like a [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) issue.

You may need to fetch the time from the server your code is being loaded from instead (which might be as simple as making an HTTP request and parsing [the `Date` header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610254/whats-the-rationale-behind-the-http-date-header); just remember to [disable caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884513/avoid-caching-of-the-http-responses)).

Using you own server as a time source is generally a better practice anyway — public NTP servers, like [those operated by NIST](http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi) are operated voluntarily and free of charge by their owners, and used by millions of people across the Internet; it's simply good manners not to place any more load on them than you have to.